# Hiding the iPhone keyboard from the View

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I'm trying to enable the desktop keyboard input to the iPhone simulator. I followed this guide to achieve this:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/2239

But calling textField.hidden=YES; only hides the field for the text, not the keyboard. I want to still be able to read input from my desktop keyboard.

Thanks

Comment: Let me try to clarify your question: you want to have text input working only in simulator using hardware keyboard without showing virtual keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [textField resignFirstResponder]

Comment: Thanks, but then the textfield does not respond to the desktop keyboard anymore. So that does not work for me.

Comment: Sorry.  I misunderstood your question.  What you want to do may be hard or impossible.  Even if you figure it out, the I wonder if the App Store might not let in an app that requires a physical keyboard...

Comment: Agreed. If this is the behavior you are after, you would be better off writing a native OSX application.

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution. See answer below. I'm not planning to submit this to the app store. I only use it to control my game in order to capture video. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. I need to find the UIKeyboard and hide that. This does the trick:

```
UIWindow* tempWindow;
for(int c = 0; c < [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] count]; c ++)
{
    tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:c];
    for(int i = 0; i < [tempWindow.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        UIView* keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES
           || [[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"] == YES 
           || [[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UISnap"] == YES ){   

            [keyboard setHidden:YES];
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the checkbox at "Hardware => Simulate Hardware Keyboard" of the iPhone simulator.